# Pygame Midi Multi Instrument

Tags: python, pygame

Is it possible to play multiple instruments at the same time in pygame.midi?
The only solution i found was
Note on,
Change instrument,
Other note on,
Note off,
Note off

But i think that is not the proper way. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

1. Each instrument that you want to use should be on its own MIDI channel (0..15). You set this using the [`set_instrument(instrument_id, channel)`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html#pygame.midi.Output.set_instrument) method.
2. Then you pass the channel number of the instrument you want to send a Note On/Off message to using the [`note_on(note, velocity, channel)`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html#pygame.midi.Output.note_on) and [`note_off(note, velocity, channel)`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/midi.html#pygame.midi.Output.note_off) methods.